# Image transformation from 2D coordinates to Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: image-processing, opencv, projection-matrix

I would like to convert a Jpeg image (its coordinates (x,y)) into a Cylindrical coordinates..

Is there a function in opencv that can do this directly? or what functions in opencv can I use to create my own??

I am having confusion between 2d coordinates, 3d coordinates and cylindrical coordinates.. can someone briefly discuss this?

Is there a mathematical algorithms available to convert 2d to 3d? 2d to cylindrical coordinates? 3d to cylindrical coordinates?

I read the previous post regarding this topic but does not understand it..

I have not take a course on image processing but I'm in a rush to read books.. 
I learn by experience and by studying other programmers code.. so source code will be much appreciated..

thanks to everyone and sorry for my elementary post,,

Comment: i would like to convert the 2d coordinates of the jpeg image into cylindrical coordinates.. I will be using the converted coordinates into image stitching function later..

Answer (score 7):

In the 2D realm, you have Polar coordinates. OpenCV has two nice functions for converting between Cartesian and Polar coordinates [cartToPolar](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=polar#void%20cartToPolar%28InputArray%20x,%20InputArray%20y,%20OutputArray%20magnitude,%20OutputArray%20angle,%20bool%20angleInDegrees%29) and [polarToCart](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=polar#void%20polarToCart%28InputArray%20magnitude,%20InputArray%20angle,%20OutputArray%20x,%20OutputArray%20y,%20bool%20angleInDegrees%29). There doesn't seem to be a good example of using these functions, so I made one for you using the `cartToPolar` function:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector<double> vX;
    vector<double> vY;

    for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            vY.push_back(y);
            vX.push_back(x);
        }
    }

    vector<double> mag;
    vector<double> angle;

    cartToPolar(vX, vY, mag, angle, true);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < mag.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Cartesian (" << vX[i] << ", " << vY[i] << ") " << "<-> Polar (" << mag[i] << ", " << angle[i] << ")" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Cylindrical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html) are the 3D version of Polar coordinates. Below is a small sample to show how you could implement cylindrical coordinates. I'm not sure where you'll be getting your 3D z-coordinate, so I just made it arbitrary (e.g., `x + y`):

```
Mat_<Vec3f> magAngleZ;

for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        Vec3f pixel;
        pixel[0] = cv::sqrt((double)x*x + (double)y*y); // magnitude
        pixel[1] = cv::fastAtan2(y, x);                 // angle
        pixel[2] = x + y;                               // z
        magAngleZ.push_back(pixel);
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < magAngleZ.rows; i++)
{
    Vec3f pixel = magAngleZ.at<Vec3f>(i, 0);
    cout << "Cylindrical (" << pixel[0] << ", " << pixel[1] << ", " << pixel[2] << ")" << endl;
}
```

If you're interested in image stitching, have a look at the [stitching.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stitching.cpp) and [stitching_detailed.cpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp) samples provided by OpenCV.

**EDIT :**
You may find these resources on [cylindrical projection](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Cylindrical%20projection#pq=cylindrical%20projection&hl=en&cp=33&gs_id=17&xhr=t&q=Cylindrical%20projection%20image%20stitching&tok=XFrkdtV9bWSe_iJTItwuXw&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&safe=off&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=Cylindrical%20projection%20image%20stit&aq=0w&aqi=q-w1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=a1bc1589ec616832&biw=1028&bih=744) helpful:

[Computer Vision: Mosaics](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&sqi=2&ved=0CEUQFjAD&url=http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2010_spring/Lectures/MoreMosaics.ppt&ei=mtPsTovuCMKatwfjsZTyCQ&usg=AFQjCNHVsp7xH1RZooC3QFfFjVKqgnbmHA&sig2=HW5Haqp06MWBZy0dPFbgvA)
[Why Mosaic?](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&sqi=2&ved=0CEwQFjAE&url=http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/CompPhoto06/html/lecturenotes/15_pano_6.pdf&ei=mtPsTovuCMKatwfjsZTyCQ&usg=AFQjCNE7dwPjPoGVfpEsn65iHfowL-pziA&sig2=LCo7riAg5ybnLwvK59oqYg)
[Automatic Panoramic Image Stitching using Invariant Features](http://mesh.brown.edu/engn1610/pdfs/Brown-ijcv2007.pdf)
[Creating full view panoramic image mosaics and environment maps](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/csep576/05wi/readings/szeliskiShum97.pdf)

Comment: Yes, you're right I'm interested in image stitching.. 
I was able to successfully run your first program but having problems in the your second source code with line >>magAngleZ.push_back(pixel);

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Appreciated. 
I have another question.. An image has pixel values located in each (x,y) coordinates. My question is if I convert my (x,y) coordinates into cylindrical coordinates will the pixel value located on that coordinate changed??

Hope you get my question.. Correct me I have misunderstanding..

Comment: @NicoleMontecalvo If you are having trouble with the `Mat::push_back()` function, you may be running an older version of OpenCV. What version are you using?

Comment: I am running opencv 2.3.0 in Codeblocks 10.05, MinGw Gnu Gcc Compiler.. 

I have read through a lot of articles.. Do i need to calibrate my camera? i will be using a casio exilim ex-z77 but the examples i saw, it seems that they are using webcameras.. Is there a way I can calibrate my camera. Correct me if I'm wrong.. This maybe different from what I initially asked.. Regards and thank you.